# How to get the tasks thats going to be done this week in excel?

Tags: excel

I am doing an agenda in excel.
I have a sheet named `ChartGantt` that has a start column (which is the start day date ) and a deadline( column with the end day date), and I have another sheet that is called `Plan-Semana` which has the weekdays with the dates.
I want to filter all the cells in the `ChartGantt` sheet  that fits in the week for example:

```
start: 01/01/2022
deadline: 30/01/2022
```

[image]

and in the `Plan-Semana` which shows the dates week by week.I would like to bring by filtering in the filter the cells in `GanttChart` and bring them to  `Plan-Semana` and put them in the week date cell. to have a week view like in google calendar, the tasks to be done in the day.

I've tried to do that each day but it's not working. I'm using this formula:

`=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;AND(GanttChart!I:I<=C25;GanttChart!J:J>=U25);"No results")`

The link is: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtPc07fC4QqykKZ2YB9Hu1AoPOnGkw?e=ezj4wh

Thanks a lot, guys

Comment: one cannot use `AND` in [`FILTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759): `=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;(GanttChart!I:I<=C25)*(GanttChart!J:J>=U25);"No results")`

Comment: It's not getting 
For monday
`=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;(GanttChart!I:I<=C25)*(GanttChart!J:J>=C25);"No results")`
For tusday
`=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;(GanttChart!I:I<=C25)*(GanttChart!J:J>=F25);"No results")`
But in saturday is  not getting the tasks that happens in saturday
`=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;(GanttChart!I:I<=C25)*(GanttChart!J:J>=R25);"No results")`
Since saturday has tasks that happens in `11/06/2022`it should appear

=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;(GanttChart!I:I<=C25)*(GanttChart!J:J>=F25);"No results")

Comment: @ScottCraner This os not getting the  R25 dates with the formula `=FILTER(GanttChart!A:A;(GanttChart!I:I<=C25)*(GanttChart!J:J>=R25);"No results")` it was to get the  tasks in that's gonna happen in "11/06/2022" do you know what could it be the mistake ?

Comment: Not without looking at your data and I do not download files from public forums.

Comment: Hey, @SpectralInstance Do you have any idea what's happening? Is with that same file you helped me once.